# How to add class to tr using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to add classes to tr .

I tried the various options belwo but didnt seem to work.. Any help would be appreciated. N

```
  //jQuery("div.flexigrid > table.flexme1 > tr").addClass("cal");

or

        jQuery("div.flexigrid > table.flexme1 > tr").addClass("sev1");
  or 
        jQuery(".erow").addClass("sev2");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid > tr").addClass("sev3");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid >tr").addClass("sev4");
   or
        jQuery(".flexigrid >tr").addClass("sev5");
```

none of teh above seem to work

I would like the tr to have the class="sev" added to it.

```
<div class="flexigrid">
  ..< some other divs>
... <some other divs>
---
<div class="bDiv" style="height: 200px;">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="flexme1" >
      <tbody>
         <tr  class="sev1">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow"  class="sev1">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">1</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr   class="sev3">
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">1</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">BM1M</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">4</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">BM1N</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="erow" >
            <td align="left" abbr="InstanceDisplayName8">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="severity" class="sorted">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="Impact">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">0</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" abbr="occurrencecount">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 40px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="NotificationID">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Host</div>
            </td>
            <td align="left" abbr="Name">
               <div style="text-align: left; width: 120px;">Down</div>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
               <div style="text-align: right; width: 130px;">undefined</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="iDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>


</div><!-- end of flexidiv>
```

Comment: the class on your div doesn't match your selector, your selectors within your if block are inconsistent, you are using the child selector `>` for elements that aren't direct children, and you have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: For `.flexigrid > tr` to work, `class="flexigrid"` would have to be on the `<tbody>`.

Comment: Basically, in response to "Not sure what i am doing wrong"... a LOT

Comment: <tr id="rowHost"  is added by the flexigrid automatically. is there any altertnate way to add class to every tr  inside table .flexme1

Comment: I was able to disable the <tr id="rowHost" it was adding. I am still unable to add a class to tr

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a div with the class `flexigrid`. You have `div.bDiv`

Second, there is an error on the table line:

```
class="flexme1 stype=&quot;display: none&quot;"
```

It should be:

```
class="flexme1" style="display: none"
```

Third, you have multiple elements with `id="rowHost"`. Elements *must* have a unique ID.

Comment: that second attribute should likely be `style`, not `stype`

Comment: nice I updated that err class="flexme1" style="display: none". I still need to apply the class to the tr

Comment: @user244394 the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selects only "direct child elements". `table.flexme1` is not a direct child of `div.flexigrid`.

Comment: Technically, elements don't HAVE to have unique IDs -- unless you want to reference the second one at some point in time. The browser will just stop at the first matching ID it finds.

Comment: @Blazemonger yeah, I suppose I could have worded it differently, but I can't think of anything you could do with multiple elements with the same id. Is there anything?

Comment: Nope. I just wanted to be clear about what the browser does with multiple identical IDs -- nothing bad, but nothing useful either.

Comment: i was able to disable the multiple id thatwas  being generated by the flexigrid. So how do i go about adding a class to tr using jquery?

Comment: Look at the first two things in my answer... mainly the first.

Answer (score 0):

first, no div in your code has the class "flexigrid" so jquery wont find what you want it to.

now, this should work

```
$("bDiv tr").addClass("sev1");
```